# Doctrine's decimal type: conversion to string locale aware?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, locale

I use a decimal field in one of my entities.

```
class MyTest {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=20, scale=2)
    */
    private $value;

    public function getValue() {
        dump($this->value);
        return floatval($this->value);        
    }
    public function setValue(float $value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

Assume I instantiate and persist a MyTest on a computer with German locale:

```
$mytest = new MyTest();
$mytest->setValue(1234.56);
```

When fetching this object form the database, `$this->value` will be the string `"1234.56"`, not a float. Moreover, this string has  **no** thousands separator and a dot (".") as decimal separator. But my (German) locale is different.

I am not sure, if the string-to-float conversion in `getValue` is correct on every system. Usually I would expect having to use `localeconv` to get the correct separators for this conversion.

However, the database (postgres) does store a numeric! *I would like to see the code where doctrine converts the query result to string*, because I need a reliable way to convert back to float.

- **Can I count on the fact that "." is the decimal separator for this conversion?** (and no thousands sep)
- Does this hold **for any locale**, and **any database type** (postgres, mysql, mssql,...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ocramius solved my problem in a [github issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/7314)

Using `floatval` would work (no locales involved here), but is **strongly discouraged** because floats cannot represent every decimal number exactly. 
The advice to use `ext-bcmath` is great!